# Why is this code generating a php.mail.multipart.form exploit malware detection from my hosting provider?

Tags: php, hosting, detection, malware, exploit

Why is this code generating a php.mail.multipart.form exploit malware detection from my hosting provider?

My hosting provider is detecting this code as containing malware?

Why is this?

it seems that the script shared is being flagged for potential malware, particularly related to a PHP Mail Multipart Form exploit. However, the script you provided appears to be a Python script and does not seem to contain any PHP code.

Given that the script shared is written in Python and does not contain any PHP code, it is unlikely that the script itself is the source of the PHP Mail Multipart Form exploit detection.

To determine the cause of the malware detection, how can i investigate other aspects of system, such as the server configuration, the environment where the script is executed, or any other files or dependencies that may be present? It is possible that there are other files or factors within your system that are triggering the malware detection?

```
<?php include 'include/header.php';?>
<?php include 'include/navbar.php';?>
<?php include 'db.php';?>

<br><br>
<br>
<div class="container col-lg-5 ">
  <div class=" home-section">
    <br>
  <div>
    <h2 class="text-primary  text-center"><b>SignUp</b></h2>
  </div>
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $email      =$_POST['email'];
    $password   =$_POST['password'];
    $c_password =$_POST['c_password'];
    $username   =$_POST['username'];
    $location   =$_POST['location'];
    $catogery   =$_POST['catogery'];
    $image      =$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_name   =$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];

    $sql1="SELECT * FROM `register` WHERE email='$email'";
    $run=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($run);
    $error = ['catogery'=>"", 'email'=>'', 'password'=>"", 
              'username'=>"", 'location'=>"", 'image'=>""];
    if (empty($catogery)) {
        $error['catogery'] = "Please Select catogery";
    }
    if (empty($image)) {
        $error['image'] = "Please Select Image";
    }
    if (empty($c_password)) {
        $error['c_password'] = "Please Enter Confirm password";
    }
    if (empty($username)) {
        $error['username'] = "Please Enter Username";
    }
    if (empty($email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please Enter Email";
    }
    if ($count>0) {
        $error['email'] = "Email is already Exists";
    }
    if (empty($password)) {
        $error['password'] = "Please Enter password";
    }
   
    if (empty($location)) {
        $error['location'] = "Please Select Location";
    }
   
    if ($password!=$c_password) {
        $error['c_password'] = "Confirm password not match";
    }
    $status="";
    if ($catogery=='client') {
        $status=1;
    }else{
        $status=0;
    }
   
    foreach ($error as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            unset($error[$key]);
        }
    }
    if (empty($error)) {
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            $sql="INSERT INTO `register`
                            (`email`, `password`, `catogery`, 
                            `username`,`location`,`image`,
                            `status`,`email_verification`) 
                    VALUES ('$email', '$password', '$catogery', 
                            '$username', '$location', '$image', 
                            '$status','0')";
            $run1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            if ($run1) {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"img/".$image);
                if ($catogery=='client') {
                    header("location:login.php");

                    $to = "$email";
                    $subject = "Verify Website";
                    $from = $hosting_email;
                    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
                    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 
                    // Create email headers
                    $headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
                            'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
                            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
                    // Compose a simple HTML email message
                    $message = "
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office'>

<head>
  <!-- NAME: 1 COLUMN -->
  <!--[if gte mso 15]>
      <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
          <o:AllowPNG/>
          <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
      </xml>
    <![endif]-->
  <meta charset='UTF-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <title>Reset Your Lingo Password</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <!--<![endif]-->
  <style type='text/css'>
    @media only screen and (min-width:768px){
          .templateContainer{
              width:600px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          body,table,td,p,a,li,blockquote{
              -webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          body{
              width:100% !important;
              min-width:100% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          #bodyCell{
              padding-top:10px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImage{
              width:100% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
         
   .mcnCaptionTopContent,.mcnCaptionBottomContent,.mcnTextContentContainer,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer,.mcnImageGroupContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightTextContentContainer,.mcnCaptionLeftImageContentContainer,.mcnCaptionRightImageContentContainer,.mcnImageCardLeftTextContentContainer,.mcnImageCardRightTextContentContainer{
              max-width:100% !important;
              width:100% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer{
              min-width:100% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageGroupContent{
              padding:9px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnCaptionLeftContentOuter
   .mcnTextContent,.mcnCaptionRightContentOuter .mcnTextContent{
              padding-top:9px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageCardTopImageContent,.mcnCaptionBlockInner
   .mcnCaptionTopContent:last-child .mcnTextContent{
              padding-top:18px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageCardBottomImageContent{
              padding-bottom:9px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageGroupBlockInner{
              padding-top:0 !important;
              padding-bottom:0 !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageGroupBlockOuter{
              padding-top:9px !important;
              padding-bottom:9px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentColumn{
              padding-right:18px !important;
              padding-left:18px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcnImageCardLeftImageContent,.mcnImageCardRightImageContent{
              padding-right:18px !important;
              padding-bottom:0 !important;
              padding-left:18px !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
          .mcpreview-image-uploader{
              display:none !important;
              width:100% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Heading 1
      @tip Make the first-level headings larger in size for better readability
   on small screens.
      */
          h1{
              /*@editable*/font-size:20px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Heading 2
      @tip Make the second-level headings larger in size for better
   readability on small screens.
      */
          h2{
              /*@editable*/font-size:20px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Heading 3
      @tip Make the third-level headings larger in size for better readability
   on small screens.
      */
          h3{
              /*@editable*/font-size:18px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Heading 4
      @tip Make the fourth-level headings larger in size for better
   readability on small screens.
      */
          h4{
              /*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Boxed Text
      @tip Make the boxed text larger in size for better readability on small
   screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
      */
          .mcnBoxedTextContentContainer
   .mcnTextContent,.mcnBoxedTextContentContainer .mcnTextContent p{
              /*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Preheader Visibility
      @tip Set the visibility of the email's preheader on small screens. You
   can hide it to save space.
      */
          #templatePreheader{
              /*@editable*/display:block !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Preheader Text
      @tip Make the preheader text larger in size for better readability on
   small screens.
      */
          #templatePreheader .mcnTextContent,#templatePreheader
   .mcnTextContent p{
              /*@editable*/font-size:12px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Header Text
      @tip Make the header text larger in size for better readability on small
   screens.
      */
          #templateHeader .mcnTextContent,#templateHeader .mcnTextContent p{
              /*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Body Text
      @tip Make the body text larger in size for better readability on small
   screens. We recommend a font size of at least 16px.
      */
          #templateBody .mcnTextContent,#templateBody .mcnTextContent p{
              /*@editable*/font-size:16px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }   @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
      /*
      @tab Mobile Styles
      @section Footer Text
      @tip Make the footer content text larger in size for better readability
   on small screens.
      */
          #templateFooter .mcnTextContent,#templateFooter .mcnTextContent p{
              /*@editable*/font-size:12px !important;
              /*@editable*/line-height:150% !important;
          }
  
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body style='-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 background-color: #fed149; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%'>
  <center>
    <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' height='100%' id='bodyTable' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:
 100%; background-color: #fed149; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width:
 100%' width='100%'>
      <tr>
        <td align='center' id='bodyCell' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; border-top: 0;
 height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%' valign='top'>
          <!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
              <table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='600' style='width:600px;'>
                <tr>
                  <td align='center' valign='top' width='600' style='width:600px;'>
                  <![endif]-->
          <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='templateContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; max-width:
 600px; border: 0' width='100%'>
            <tr>
              <td id='templatePreheader' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #fed149;
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom: 8px' valign='top'>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                  <tbody class='mcnTextBlockOuter'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='mcnTextBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%' valign='top'>
                        <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextContentContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:
 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td class='mcnTextContent' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; word-break: break-word;
 color: #2a2a2a; font-family: 'Asap, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px;
 line-height: 150%; text-align: left; padding-top:9px; padding-right: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 9px; padding-left: 18px; valign='top'>
                                <a href='http://website.com/' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #2a2a2a;
 font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none' target='_blank' title='Lingo is the
 best way to organize, share and use all your visual assets in one place -
 all on your desktop.'>
                                  <img align='none' height='32' src='http://website.com/img/logo.png' style='-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; outline: none;
 text-decoration: none; height: auto; width: 107px; height: 32px; margin: 0px;' width='107' />
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id='templateHeader' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #f7f7ff;
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom: 0' valign='top'>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnImageBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                  <tbody class='mcnImageBlockOuter'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='mcnImageBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; padding:0px' valign='top'>
                        <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnImageContentContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:
 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td class='mcnImageContent' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; padding-right: 0px;
 padding-left: 0px; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:center;' valign='top'>
                                <a class='' href='https://www.lingoapp.com' style='mso-line-height-rule:
 exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color:
 #f57153; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none' target='_blank' title=''>
                                  <a class='' href='http://website.com/' style='mso-line-height-rule:
 exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; color:
 #f57153; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none' target='_blank' title=''>
                                    <img align='center' alt='Forgot your password?' class='mcnImage' src='img/verify.png' style='-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; border: 0; height: auto; outline: none;
 text-decoration: none; vertical-align: bottom; height: 300px; max-width:300px; padding-bottom:
 0; display: inline !important; vertical-align: bottom;' width='600'></img>
                                  </a>
                                </a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td id='templateBody' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #f7f7ff;
 border-top: 0; border-bottom: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0' valign='top'>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                  <tbody class='mcnTextBlockOuter'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='mcnTextBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%' valign='top'>
                        <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextContentContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:
 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td class='mcnTextContent' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; word-break: break-word;
 color: #2a2a2a; font-family: 'Asap', Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px;
 line-height: 150%; text-align: center; padding-top:9px; padding-right: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 9px; padding-left: 18px;' valign='top'>

                                <h1 class='null' style='color: #2a2a2a; font-family: 'Asap', Helvetica,
 sans-serif; font-size: 32px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height:
 125%; letter-spacing: 2px; text-align: center; display: block; margin: 0;
 padding: 0'><span style='text-transform:uppercase'></span></h1>


                                <h2 class='null' style='color: #2a2a2a; font-family: Asap, Helvetica,
 sans-serif; font-size: 24px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; line-height:
 125%; letter-spacing: 1px; text-align: center; display: block; margin: 0;
 padding: 0'><span style='text-transform:uppercase'><center>Email Verification</center></span></h2>

                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace:
 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                  <tbody class='mcnTextBlockOuter'>
                    <tr>
                      <td class='mcnTextBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%' valign='top'>
                        <table align='left' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnTextContentContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:
 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <td class='mcnTextContent' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; word-break: break-word;
 color: #2a2a2a; font-family: Asap, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center; padding-top:9px; padding-right: 18px;
  padding-left: 18px; color:white; background-color:#F57153;'><h1><center> 
  Thank you for registering. Please click the link below to verify your email address.<br>
   <br>
Best Regards,
<br>
The Verification Team</center><h1>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                        
                                <br></br>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnButtonBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                  <tbody class='mcnButtonBlockOuter'>
                    <tr>
                      <td align='center' class='mcnButtonBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule:
 exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 padding-top:18px; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:18px; padding-left:18px;' valign='top'>
                        <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnButtonBlock' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0; mso-table-rspace: 0;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; min-width:100%;' width='100%'>
                          <tbody class='mcnButtonBlockOuter'>
                            <tr>
                              <td align='center' class='mcnButtonBlockInner' style='mso-line-height-rule:
 exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 padding-top:0; padding-right:18px; padding-bottom:18px; padding-left:18px;' valign='top'>
                                <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' class='mcnButtonContentContainer' style='border-collapse: collapse; mso-table-lspace: 0;
 mso-table-rspace: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 border-collapse: separate !important;border-radius: 48px;background-color:
 #04AA6D;'>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td align='center' class='mcnButtonContent' style='mso-line-height-rule:
 exactly; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 font-family: Asap, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; padding-top:24px;
 padding-right:48px; padding-bottom:24px; padding-left:48px;' valign='middle'>
                                        <a class='mcnButton ' href='$website_domain/account-verfication.php?email=$user_email' style='mso-line-height-rule: exactly;
 -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; display: block; color: #f57153;
 font-weight: normal; text-decoration: none; font-weight: normal;letter-spacing:
 1px;line-height: 100%;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;color:
 #FFFFFF; text-transform:uppercase; padding:10px;' target='_blank' title='Review Lingo kit
 invitation'>Clink Here To Verify Your Account</a>
                                      </td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                        </table>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
               
          <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            <![endif]-->
          <!-- // END TEMPLATE -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
";
 
                if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
   
                }else{

                }
            }else{
                header("location:provider-details.php?email=$email&&name=$username&&location=$location");
            }
        }
    } 
}
}
?>
    <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username"  class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['username'])) {
    echo $error['username'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['email'])) {
    echo $error['email'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <label>Profile Image</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control" placeholder="Please Select Profile Image">
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['image'])) {
   echo $error['image'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['password'])) {
   echo $error['password'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <label>Confirm Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="c_password" class="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password">
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['c_password'])) {
   echo $error['c_password'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <label>Select Location</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="location">
            <option value="">Select Location</option>
<?php 
$sql="SELECT * FROM `location`";
$i=1;
$run1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run1)) {
?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row['id'];?>"><?php echo $row['name'];?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
        </select>
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['location'])) {
   echo $error['location'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between col-md-8">
            <p>I'm a: </p>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" checked name="catogery" value="client">Client
            </label>
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="catogery" value="provider">Provider
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="text-danger">  
<?php 
if (isset($error['catogery'])) {
   echo $error['catogery'];
}
?>
        </div><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    </form><br>
    <p class=" text-center">
  Don't Have Any Account?<a href="login.php" class="btn btn-link">Login</a>
  </p>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<br><br>

<?php include 'include/footer.php';?>
```

Comment: Well, since they've incorrectly identified the script as python instead of PHP, I'd be questioning whether their wider diagnosis has any merit?

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unparameterised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli also contains good examples of writing safe SQL using mysqli. See also the [mysqli documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and this: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) . Parameterising your queries will also greatly reduce the risk of accidental syntax errors as a result of un-escaped or incorrectly quoted input values. If you learnt your current technique from a tutorial or book, please don't use that resource again.

Comment: Also, please don't store passwords in plain text - that is another security risk. Learn about [password hashing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead. See also [How to use PHP's password_hash to hash and verify passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279321/how-to-use-phps-password-hash-to-hash-and-verify-passwords)

Comment: I'd also suggest you take steps to validate that the email being entered definitely looks like an email address and doesn't contain any other content, and maybe that the message content doesn't contain things like additional HTML tags, or script. This can help to prevent certain kinds of email exploits. And rather than building raw email headers by hand, use a library like PHPMailer for a more robust and secure approach.

Comment: Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.